# How do I run an additional process after the Apex data load wizard has finished

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

A user is uploading a file to apex using the data load wizard. What I want to do is after the data load wizard has finished inserting/ updating the data in the database table,  I want to run a piece of  code,  specifically a merge on the records then an additional update.

I'm thinking I need to input an additional process on third or fourth Page of the data load wizard,  but not sure where the best place would be for it. Thanks

Below is the code I wish to add:

```
truncate table TEMP_UPLOAD;
Merge into INVOICE b
USING (
 SELECT CUSTOMER_CLASS,RULE_AGGREGATOR,BA
 FROM CUSTOMER_TEMP_UPLOAD
 WHERE CUSTOMER_CLASS = 'CUSTOMER88') u
ON (b.BA = u.BA)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET b.CUSTOMER88_DATE_UPDATED = sysdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (b.CUSTOMER_CLASS,b.RULE_AGGREGATOR,b.BA,b.CUSTOMER88_DATE_ADDED)
  VALUES (u.CUSTOMER_CLASS,u.RULE_AGGREGATOR,u.BA,sysdate);

UPDATE INVOICE a 
    SET a.CUSTOMER88_DATE_REMOVED = sysdate
    WHERE BA IN 
        (select b.BA 
 from INVOICE b 
 left join CUSTOMER_temp_upload u 
 on b.BA = u.BA 
 where u.BA is null and b.CUSTOMER_CLASS = 'CUSTOMER88');
```

Below are screenshots of the dataload wizard. Note the wizard starts with Pg2. Pg1 is the home screen.

[image: Pg2]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots or code so far ?

Comment: @coffee just at work will put screenshots and code when get home

Comment: @Coffee Cool, added in the code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page 4 has a process `Prepare Uploaded Data` which actually does the data loading.

You can add an additional process after that point that will run after the data was loaded.

Comment: thanks @Jeffrey , now just to get the pl/sql block working :(. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563838/how-do-i-convert-sql-code-to-pl-sql-for-an-apex-process)